# Declare Array properties without values - knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

http://jsfiddle.net/HXZ2u/19/

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.products = ko.observableArray([{
        pname: '',     //Declare props. without values ??
        qty: ''
    }]);
}
```

The table is bound by an observableArray. 
Clicking on `edit` fills the row values in respective textboxes. Clicking on `update` will update the array with modified values.
Everything works fine. Just that, there is an empty row created first ( see in Fiddle). This is because of

```
pname: '',qty: ''
```

1. So, how to avoid this, so that the table can have only the defined 'products' and not the empty row.
2. I'm using jquery to get the row index on clicking 'Edit'. How to get this with KO.

Comment: you can assign the property values as `undefined` also!!!

Comment: It still adds an empty row at 0 index

Comment: You shouldn't use jQuery to alter the DOM from the viewmodel it defeats the purpose of MVVM!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create that first object, unless you want it to be in the list. Simply omitting it allows you to create the array with no objects, then your other objects will be added into the array later.

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.products = ko.observableArray(); // products is an empty observable Array
}
```

The error you were probably getting is because below, you were binding to `selected().pname`, but `selected()` was undefined initially. You can wrap that block in a virtual `if` binding, so it's removed until an item is selected.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sG2gU/1/)

Edit, missed your second question:

To get the index of the item, you can use `ko.contextFor`:

```
 self.select = function(item, event){
    var context = ko.contextFor(event.target);
    alert('the ID is: ' + context.$index());
    self.selected(item);
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on this answer? If I start from the OP's initial code and simply remove the initialization, I get a binding error

Comment: @Anzeo I already did. See my paragraph beneath the code block.